# How to display unique nomenclature parameters?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

I am using the  *nomenclature* package to define nomenclatures in various chapters of a thesis. I am new to using this package and doing this using e.g.

```
\nomenclature[z-ANN]{ANN}{Artificial Neural Network}.
```

However, the same term may occur in different chapters- as (unintentionally), I have defined some terms more than once and as a result, they are appearing multiple times in the main thesis document.
The nomenclatures are displayed using `\printnomenclature`.

Is there a way to only display the unique nomenclature contents (e.g. ANN is only displayed once in the main nomenclature, even though it may have been defined multiple times. Thanks

EDIT- Turns out that there is a simple way of doing this with the `acro` package!

Comment: This is rather simple with the `acro` package. I'll post an answer with it if you're interested. (I don't know the `nomencl` package very well so I'm not giving advice on its usage. Maybe there is an easy solution as well)

Comment: Hi @cgnieder -I would love to know how to do this with the acro package. Basically, I was having this difficulty with nomencl so am happy to switch to a different package for future needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution with the `nomencl` package but an alternative using the `acro` package (as per request in a comment to the question): `acro` allows the creation of “local” list of acronyms which only list the acronyms that were used in between two uses of `\acbarrier`. In addition a list of *all* acronyms can be created. This way there is no need to define acronyms mutiple times.

```
\printacronyms % complete list
\acbarrier
...
\printacronyms[local] % local list
\acbarrier
...
\printacronyms[local] % another local list
\acbarrier
```

These barriers can be called automatically, for example by adding them to the `\section` command. The example below demonstrates this using `\preto` (provided by the `etoolbox` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use = true ,
  barriers/reset = true
}

\newcommand\printsectionacronyms[1]{%
  \printacronyms[local,heading=none,preamble=\subsection{Acronyms to Section #1}]
}

\DeclareAcronym{ANN}{
  short = ANN ,
  long = Artificial Neural Network
}
\DeclareAcronym{xx}{
  short = xx ,
  long = just a test
}
\DeclareAcronym{yy}{
  short = yy ,
  long = another test
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% make every \section a barrier:
\preto\section{\acbarrier}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms[name=All Acronyms in the Document]

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo Subsection}
\ac{xx} and \ac{ANN}

\printsectionacronyms{Foo}

\section{Bar}
\subsection{Bar Subsection}

\ac{ANN} and text

\printsectionacronyms{Bar}

\section{Baz}
\subsection{Baz Subsection}

\ac{xx} and \ac{yy}

\printsectionacronyms{Baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]